# Bootstrap touch carousel need to be infinite loop

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

In Bootstrap carousel I have add touch support(bootstrap-touch-carousel.js). After that interval cycle stop working it will stop after last slide I want it infinite loop. It is working in web but not working in mobile. My code is below:

```
$('.carousel').carousel({ 
                interval: 2000,
                pause: "false"
                  });
```

Comment: What's bootstrap-touch-carousel.js or where is it from?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution, works for me:

Find:

```
f.prototype._showPane = function(a) {
  this.$items.eq(this.current_pane).toggleClass("active"), a >= this.pane_count && this.pause(), a = Math.max(0, Math.min(a, this.pane_count - 1)), this.$items.eq(a).toggleClass("active"), this.current_pane = a;
  var b = -(100 / this.pane_count * this.current_pane);
  return this._setContainerOffset(b, !0, a), this
}
```

Replace for:

```
f.prototype._showPane = function(a) {
  if (a >= this.$items.length){ a = 0; }
  this.$items.eq(this.current_pane).toggleClass("active"), a >= this.pane_count && this.pause(), a = Math.max(0, Math.min(a, this.pane_count - 1)), this.$items.eq(a).toggleClass("active"), this.current_pane = a;
  var b = -(100 / this.pane_count * this.current_pane);
  return this._setContainerOffset(b, !0, a), this
}

<a href="http://clustersystems.devrun.com/frontapp/js/bootstrap-touch-carousel-custom.js">Here the JS library</a>
```